# cyclotomic polynomial and unit group

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $a$ ne a nonzero integer, p a prime, n a positive integer, and p does not divide n. Prove that $p | \Phi_{n}(a)$ if and only if a has period n in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{*}$

Actually I have almost done, I know how to prove from the right to the left, but when I do from the left to the right, I can not show that for any $d < n$ is a factor of $n$, $a^{d}$ is not $1$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{*}$. To prove this, I think we must use the condition p does not divide n, but don't knwo how.

Any hint is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: if $a$ has order $n$ in $(\mathbb{Z}_p,\times)$ then $p | a^n -1$, and $p$ doesn't divides $a^d-1$ for any $d < n$, in particular for any $d | n$. now, what happens if the order of $a$ is $d$ ? then $p | a^d-1$, and $\frac{a^n-1}{a^d-1} = \ldots$

Comment: if $n = md$ and $p|a^{d}-1$, then $(a^{n}-1)/(a^{d}-1) = a^{(m-1)d}+a^{(m-2)d}+ \cdots +1$, and I also know that we have $p^{2}|a^{n}-1$, but how to get the contradiction?